# How to add a post image in Ghost's index?

Tags: node.js, ghost-blog

I don't see any examples in the docs on how to use a post's image on the index view of Ghost. For example, you can see this theme doing it: http://studio-lite-theme.ghostify.io/

Any ideas?

EDIT: If anyone comes across this, I found this post that helped: https://ghost.org/forum/themes/1401-tip-how-to-show-the-pic-of-your-post-in-index-hbs/

Answer (score 2):

Since version `0.5.2` there's now official support for Post Images. So avoid the hack using `{{content words="0"}}`

**Instead use `{{image}}` to print out the url for the image.**

For example:
`<header {{#if image}}" style="background-image: url({{image}}){{/if}}">`

Answer (score 1):

As @user3088077 mentioned in his edit, I could make the image appear in the index page by replacing in the index.hbs

from `{{ excerpt }}` to `{{content words="0"}}`.

What happens is that `excerpt` does not include images, while `content` does.

Answer (score 0):

This is aimed towards displaying the featured image in index which means it needs to be on the front page not on post page.